# Starting out with XML

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

Just starting out with XML, having a bit of trouble. I have a XML document that I have already created. This xml document is being used as a database for registered users of my website.

customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customers>
<customer>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Willson</lastname>
    <email>a@b.c</email>
    <custid>1111</custid>
    <password>Pa$$w0rd</password>
</customer>
```

I'm creating the registration page at the moment and so I need to be able to add a new customer to my existing xml document. After looking around a little this is what I came up with in my registration function:

```
$xmlFile = "customer.xml";
$dom = DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);

$customer = $dom->createElement( "Customer" );
$firstname = $dom->createElement( "firstname" );
$lastname = $dom->createElement( "lastname" );
$email = $dom->createElement( "email" );
$password = $dom->createElement( "password" );
$custid = $dom->createElement( "custid" );

$firstname->setAttribute( "firstname", "Fred" );
$lastname->setAttribute( "lastname", "Fredson" );
$email->setAttribute( "email", "d@e.f" );
$password->setAttribute( "password", "Pa$$w0rd2" );
$custid->setAttribute( "custid", "2222" );

$customer->appendChild($firstname);
$customer->appendChild($lastname);
$customer->appendChild($email);
$customer->appendChild($password);
$customer->appendChild($custid);
```

I follow that up with a "print $dom->saveXML();" but unfortunately it shows that there has been no change at all in the xml document. It just displays the information shown in the original. I'm quite new at XML so any sort of explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be great.

Cheers,

Comment: You'd be better off using a real database.

Comment: Your are missing `</customers>` at the end

Comment: An XML consists of nodes, the elements are the most obvious but only one type. You have separate methods to create a node (creatElement, createTextNode, ...) http://stackoverflow.com/a/21760903/2265374

Comment: I hope it's just a personal project to teach yourself XML and DOM. It's very difficult to get concurrent access right with plain files, not to mention how badly XML scales.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're apparently not seeing PHP notices (and maybe warnings and errors) because your code triggers some of them:

```
// Strict standards: Non-static method DOMDocument::load() should not be called statically
$dom = DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);
```

You want:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($xmlFile);
```

```php
// Notice: Undefined variable: w0rd2
$password->setAttribute( "password", "Pa$$w0rd2" );
```

You want:

```
$password->setAttribute( "password", 'Pa$$w0rd2' ); // Single quotes
```

You need to configure full error reporting before going ahead.

Fixed that, there're some other issues. XML is case sensitive:

```
$customer = $dom->createElement( "Customer" );
```

You want:

```
$customer = $dom->createElement( "customer" );
```

You create this node and you attach everything else to it, but you never insert it in the document. You want:

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('customers')->item(0)->appendChild($customer);
```

Additionally, as already pointed out in another answer, your sample XML does not use attributes. You need to create additional nodes for your data. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You have forgotten to append the new node "customer" node to the (futur) parent node "customers", and you have written a C uppercase to "Customer". You are setting the node content of your new nodes as  attributes, but these are node values (or children nodes, text nodes), not attributes.

```
$xmlFile = "customer.xml";
$dom = DOMDocument::load($xmlFile);

$customer = $dom->createElement( "customer" ); // here
$firstname = $dom->createElement( "firstname" );
$lastname = $dom->createElement( "lastname" );
$email = $dom->createElement( "email" );
$password = $dom->createElement( "password" );
$custid = $dom->createElement( "custid" );

$firstname->nodeValue = 'Fred';
$lastname->nodeValue = 'Fredson';
$email->nodeValue = 'd@e.f';
$password->nodeValue = 'Pa$$w0rd2'; // be careful with $ and double quotes
$custid->nodeValue = '2222';

$customer->appendChild($firstname);
$customer->appendChild($lastname);
$customer->appendChild($email);
$customer->appendChild($password);
$customer->appendChild($custid);

$dom->getElementsByTagName('customers')->item(0)->appendChild($customer);
```

Comment: Do not set the nodeValue directly. Here is a problem with the entity handling: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31613

Answer (score -1):

Simple XML is your answer.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

```
$customerXml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlFile);

$customerXml->addChild("firstname","Jhon");
$customerXml->addChild("lastname","Willson");
$customerXml->addChild("email","a@b.c");
$customerXml->addChild("custid","1111");
$customerXml->addChild("password","P$$w0rd");
$customerXml->asXML($file);
```

Comment: Reminder: SimpleXML will choke with badly formatted XML.

Comment: Correct, but it is simpler if the programmer can't get something else to work.