# XML with multiple roots

Tags: php, xml

Hi i've been trying to generate the following XML with PHP.

I've managed to generate it all except for the location section as it seems to treat it as another root and error out. Does anyone know the correct way to produce this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <classifieds xmlns="http://www.bdjjobs.com/ClassifiedJobFromRecruiterFeed">
    <job>
      <reference_id>20161114-72</reference_id>
      <recruiter>Smiles R Us</recruiter>
      <job_title>Denture Specialist</job_title>
      <short_description><![CDATA[An exciting position in a dynamic dental practice]]></short_description>
      <description><![CDATA[<p>Full description of post</p>]]></description>
      <location>
        <city>city</city>
        <state>county</state>
        <country>country</country>
      </location>
      <salary_description><![CDATA[Full Package]]></salary_description>
      <organisations>Independent Dental Practice</organisations>
      <job_type>Specialist Appointments</job_type>
      <salary_band>£100,000 or more</salary_band>
      <contract_type>Associate Permanent</contract_type>
      <hours>Full time</hours>
      <practice_type>Mixed (NHS/Private)</practice_type>
      <start_date>2016-09-01</start_date>
      <expiry_date>2016-10-30</expiry_date>
      <application_email>apply_here@email.com</application_email>
    </job>
  </classifieds>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Here is the code:

```
// Start Job Element
$job_element = $xml_document->createElement("job");

// Job ID
$rootreferencenumber = $xml_document->createElement("reference_id");
$rootreferencenumber->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( get_the_ID() ));
$job_element->appendChild($rootreferencenumber);

// Recruiter
$recruiter = $xml_document->createElement("recruiter");
$recruiter->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( "MBR Dental Recruitment" ));
$job_element->appendChild($recruiter);

// Job title
$title = $xml_document->createElement("title");
$title->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( get_the_title() ) );
$job_element->appendChild($title);

// Job Description
$description = $xml_document->createElement("description");
$description->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( ( strip_tags( str_replace( "</p>", "\n\n", get_the_content() ) ) ) ) );
$job_element->appendChild($description);

// City
$city = $xml_document->createElement("city");
$get_city = explode( ',', get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'geolocation_city', true ) );
$city->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $get_city[0] ) );
$job_element->appendChild($city);

// Region from Taxonomy
$region = $xml_document->createElement("region");
$categories = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'job_listing_region', array( "fields" => "names" ) );
if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
    $region->appendChild( $xml_document->createCDATASection( implode( ',', $categories ) ) );
} else {
    $region->appendChild( $xml_document->createCDATASection( '' ) );
}
$job_element->appendChild($region);


// Create Company Name
$company_name = $xml_document->createElement("organisations");
$company_name->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection('xx'));
$job_element->appendChild($company_name);

// Create Phone Number
$phone_number = $xml_document->createElement("phone_number");
$phone_number->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection('0000'));
$job_element->appendChild($phone_number);

// Job direct URL
$url = $xml_document->createElement("application_url");
$url->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection(get_permalink( get_the_ID() )));
$job_element->appendChild($url);

// Category
$phone_number = $xml_document->createElement("job_type");
$phone_number->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection('Job'));
$job_element->appendChild($phone_number);

// Subcategory
$region = $xml_document->createElement("subcategory");
$categories = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'job_listing_category', array( "fields" => "names" ) );
if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
    $region->appendChild( $xml_document->createCDATASection( implode( ',', $categories ) ) );
} else {
    $region->appendChild( $xml_document->createCDATASection( '' ) );
}
$job_element->appendChild($region);


// Job date based on todays date
$date = $xml_document->createElement("start_date");
$date->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection(date(Ymd) ));
$job_element->appendChild($date);

// Job date expire from original post date
$expiry_date = $xml_document->createElement("expiry_date");
$wpDate = (date(Ymd) );
$wpDate = new DateTime($wpDate);
$wpDate->add(new DateInterval('P14D')); // P14D means a period of 14 days
$wpDate = $wpDate->format('Ymd');
$expiry_date->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $wpDate ));
$job_element->appendChild($expiry_date);

// Create Application Email Address
$app_email = $xml_document->createElement("application_email");
$app_email->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection('xx@xx.com'));
$job_element->appendChild($app_email);

// End Job Element
$root->appendChild($job_element);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "for the section"? Which section? Or am I blind?

Comment: @1up apologies, i wrapped the word location in brackets and it didn't display. i meant the location section. i've edited the above post now. thanks

Comment: I can't say I tried doing something like this in the past, but can I see the code so that I can try to help?

Comment: Your shown XML does not have multiple roots; that wouldn't well-formed.  Your question doesn't include your code; add it to help us help you, or your post will be likely be closed as incomplete.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes thanks, added code now..

Comment: sidenote, you're probably better off not using CDATA. There's very few cases where that's a good idea.

Comment: I also still don't see the xml that generates the location section

Comment: @Evert yeah, every time i try it, its breaks! so just posting what is working so far!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i was approaching this completely wrong..

I needed to append the child elements (City + Region) to the new $location element. Not to the original $job_element

here is the correct code:

```
// Start Job Element
$job_element = $xml_document->createElement("job");

// Job ID
$rootreferencenumber = $xml_document->createElement("reference_id");
$rootreferencenumber->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( get_the_ID() ));
$job_element->appendChild($rootreferencenumber);

// Recruiter
$recruiter = $xml_document->createElement("recruiter");
$recruiter->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( "xx" ));
$job_element->appendChild($recruiter);

// Job title
$title = $xml_document->createElement("title");
$title->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( get_the_title() ) );
$job_element->appendChild($title);

// Job Description
$description = $xml_document->createElement("description");
$description->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( ( strip_tags( str_replace( "</p>", "\n\n", get_the_content() ) ) ) ) );
$job_element->appendChild($description);

//Create Location Element
$location = $xml_document->createElement("location");
$job_element->appendChild($location);

// City
$city = $xml_document->createElement("city");
$get_city = explode( ',', get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'geolocation_city', true ) );
$city->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $get_city[0] ) );
$location->appendChild($city);

// Region from Taxonomy
$region = $xml_document->createElement("region");
$categories = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'job_listing_region', array( "fields" => "names" ) );
if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
    $region->appendChild( $xml_document->createCDATASection( implode( ',', $categories ) ) );
} else {
    $region->appendChild( $xml_document->createCDATASection( '' ) );
}
$location->appendChild($region);

// Country Code
$country = $xml_document->createElement("country");
$country->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection('UK'));
$location->appendChild($country);

// Create Company Name
$company_name = $xml_document->createElement("organisations");
$company_name->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection('xx'));
$job_element->appendChild($company_name);

// Create Phone Number
$phone_number = $xml_document->createElement("phone_number");
$phone_number->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection('xx'));
$job_element->appendChild($phone_number);

// Job direct URL
$url = $xml_document->createElement("application_url");
$url->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection(get_permalink( get_the_ID() )));
$job_element->appendChild($url);

// Category
$job_type = $xml_document->createElement("job_type");
$job_type->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection('Job'));
$job_element->appendChild($job_type);

// Subcategory
$region = $xml_document->createElement("subcategory");
$categories = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'job_listing_category', array( "fields" => "names" ) );
if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $categories ) ) {
    $region->appendChild( $xml_document->createCDATASection( implode( ',', $categories ) ) );
} else {
    $region->appendChild( $xml_document->createCDATASection( '' ) );
}
$job_element->appendChild($region);


// Job date based on todays date
$date = $xml_document->createElement("start_date");
$date->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection(date(Ymd) ));
$job_element->appendChild($date);

// Job date expire from original post date
$expiry_date = $xml_document->createElement("expiry_date");
$wpDate = (date(Ymd) );
$wpDate = new DateTime($wpDate);
$wpDate->add(new DateInterval('P14D')); // P14D means a period of 14 days
$wpDate = $wpDate->format('Ymd');
$expiry_date->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( $wpDate ));
$job_element->appendChild($expiry_date);

// Create Application Email Address
$app_email = $xml_document->createElement("application_email");
$app_email->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection('x@xx.net'));
$job_element->appendChild($app_email);

// End Job Element
$root->appendChild($job_element);
```

Comment: this is where I found my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759632/creating-sub-element-in-xml